# Why _.pick(object, _.identity) in lodash returns empty Object?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to move underscore to lodash. But this line of code baffles me.

On my current project we have this line of code.

```
obj = _.pick(obj, _.identity);
```

Which is pretty obvious that it's trying to delete empty property.

Now when I switch to lodash, the same line of code returns empty object for me.

I'm trying to figure why. How do I achieve the same effect in lodash?

I tried this on both lodash and underscore websites. They produce different results.

This is from lodash

```
var obj = {_v:'10.1', uIP:'10.0.0.0', _ts:'123'}
_.pick(obj, _.identity);
Object {}
```

This is from underscore

```
var obj = {_v:'10.1', uIP:'10.0.0.0', _ts:'123'}
_.pick(obj, _.identity);
Object {_v: "10.1", uIP: "10.0.0.0", _ts: "123"}
```

Comment: Have a look at the docs: https://lodash.com/docs#pick (and notice the method that comes *after* that).

Comment: Oh, that's it. I thought lodash is compatible with underscore. If you can put that as the answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: felix is a beast, so fast....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why _.pick(object, _.identity) in lodash returns empty Object?

Because [`pick`](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) in lodash expects an **array** of property **names** to be passed to it:

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };

_.pick(object, ['a', 'c']);
// → { 'a': 1, 'c': 3 }
```

> How do I achieve the same effect in lodash?

Lodash has a method called [`pickBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#pickBy) which accepts a callback function:

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };

_.pickBy(object, _.isNumber);
// → { 'a': 1, 'c': 3 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, lodash has a slightly different name for this method than underscore:

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };

_.pickBy(object, _.isNumber);
// → { 'a': 1, 'c': 3 }
```